# Check time by broadcast receiver not work at all

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, android-broadcast

I try to make my broadcast check if the time change or not because I want to check the time every minute I put this

```
android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED android.intent.action.TIME_SET android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
```

But it don't work what can I do.

Answer (score 0):

```
//use these intent filter


   s_intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
    s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
}
```

// implement the a broadcast:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver m_timeChangedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {                                                                                             
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED) ||
                    action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_TICK)) {

            // your work
        }
    }
};
```

// register the receiver:

```
public void onCreate()/onResume {
    super.onCreate();
    registerReceiver(m_timeChangedReceiver, s_intentFilter);     
}
```

// and unregister it:

```
public void onDestroy()/onPause {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(m_timeChangedReceiver);     
}
```